# Does "accents" include also the breve and caron?

Tags: diacritical-marks

The NOAD uses *accent* also for the circumflex accent, but in the description for *breve* it doesn't say *accent*.

Does *accents* include also the breve and the caron, or does it strictly apply to *acute*, *double acute*, *grave*, and *double grave* as the list to the right in the [Wikipedia article about *diacritics*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) seems to suggest?

As Italian, I am used to use *accents* for those diacritics over a letter (over vowels, but that is because Italian doesn't use accents over consonants). Would I use *accents* in the wrong way, if I meant that in English?

Comment: In a formal context it might matter, but as far as conversational English, people should know what you mean when you say accents.  Since English doesn't really use accents except for words from other languages, it's not a common issue.

Comment: Yes, accent marks are only a subset of diacritical  marks. The breve and the caron are not accent marks.

Comment: @Tofystedeth The topic of a conversation could be the spelling of words in other languages. I would not say it is that uncommon.

Comment: ***Accent breve*** is the name of it in *French*, not English (as you obviously realize, we call it a ***circumflex***). In their definition #1 of ***accent*** the full OED includes the note ***Originally**, with reference to Greek and Latin, the set was limited to three members, the **acute, circumflex,** and **grave** accent.* But it's also defined as 2: *Any of various cantillation marks placed over and under the consonants in the written text of the Hebrew Bible* and 3: *A mark in an early text indicative of a musical or quasi-musical intonation or a punctuating phrase.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are confusing the diacritics: _breve_, a written or printed mark (˘) indicating a short or unstressed vowel. I mean the diacritic in _kaŭ_, not the one in _ŝtelis_. (Don't pay attention to the words; they are Esperanto.)

Comment: I was just pointing out that OED says "accent" *originally* only applied to those three. But their definition includes *any of these **and other marks** used to distinguish different qualities of sound indicated by a letter*, so I guess that would now cover *all* such marks. I assume you've noted [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breve) ***Inverted breve or arch** is a diacritical mark, shaped like the top half of a circle (   ̑ ), that is, like an upside-down breve ( ˘ ). It looks similar to the circumflex ( ˆ ), but the circumflex has a sharp tip; the inverted breve is rounded.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers You said, _Accent breve is the name of it in French, not English (as you obviously realize, we call it a circumflex)._ That is not exact.  You cannot even confuse a breve with a circumflex. Eventually, you could confuse a breve with a a caron.

Comment: oic. But ignoring ***of it*** in my first comment (who cares what "it" is?), you're asking whether ***accent*** includes [blah blah], and OED says it's now used of ***any of these and other marks***, so I'd have thought that answers your question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understood your comment. It just contained an inexact part, and I commented on that.

Comment: The truth is I don't have a lot of time for accents (I'd rarely use one in *cliche*, and never in *cafe*, for example). I knew there was such a thing as an "upside down" circumflex, but until now I hadn't known that it might make a difference whether the central point is angled or rounded. References to [*accents **and** diacritical marks*](http://www.businessballs.com/diacriticalmarks.htm) imply they're *not* identical, but [this source](http://wikidiff.com/diacritic/accent) says *accent is a **synonym** of diacritic* (before going on to explain the ***difference*** between them! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context (and even the orthography you are talking about):

#### Intonation and stress

You can use the word *accent* when you want to talk about the actual pronunciation of a word, i.e., the [phonetic accent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accent_(phonetics)). For instance, one of the many definitions of *accent* in the [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/accent#Noun) is:

> A mark or character used in writing, in order to indicate the place of the spoken accent, or to indicate the nature or quality of the vowel marked.

Or, in [Merriam–Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accent) (emphasis mine:

> a mark (as ´, `, ˆ) used in writing or printing to indicate a specific sound value, **stress, or pitch**, to distinguish words otherwise identically spelled, or to indicate that an ordinarily mute vowel should be pronounced

For example, you could say:

> Your intonation of *τόνος* was wrong; mind the accent!

In this sense, it obviously only makes sense to talk about a diacritical mark as an accent if it actually indicates a phonetic accent in the language you are talking about. For example, in the [Finnish orthography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finnish_orthography) the caron does not have the role of an accent – it is only placed on consonants, where it indicates a completely different pronunciation. However, the caron is used to indicate the third tone in [Pinyin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin#Tones) and thus is an accent in that orthography.

#### Typography

In my experience (being a hobby type designer), type designers and similar prefer to use *diacritical marks* instead of *accent.* Because what is a phonetic accent in one language has some other function in the next one, this makes sense: For type designers, such pronunciation details do not matter and they cannot possibly keep track of every possible language anyway.

However, the typical speaker of English (and other languages with analogous words) is more likely to know the word *accent* than *diacritical mark* and thus *accent* has become a synonym for *diacritical mark.* Since a language is formed by its speakers, I would not consider it wrong to write:

> *Měšťáčtější* is a word with a lot of accents, many of them carons.

To repeat one of the above dictionary definitions (with different emphasis):

> a mark (as ´, `, ˆ) used in writing or printing to indicate a specific **sound value**, stress, or pitch, […]

Another evidence of the above and slightly different case is the use of *accent* in mathematics, which is the predominant term for diacritical marks placed on mathematical symbols – usually to distinguish them. See for example [this page](http://www.ams.org/membership/texcodes) by the American Mathematical Society. This is completely detached from phonetics, but I would never use *diacritical mark* to talk about math accents with mathematicians.

Comment: Obviously, I am not talking of pronunciation, if I am talking of circumflex accent and breve. Plus, a breve is not a caron.

Comment: *Plus, a breve is not a caron.* – Where did I confused those?